# Sending Location name variable thru UIStoryBoardSegue not showing

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have been trying to pass a variable from one view controller to another. My first view controller collects the value of the variable and passes it via UIStoryboardSegue to **"WeatherTableViewController"**. In **"WeatherTableViewController"** I have applied the value to the search bar. I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. When I watch the value in debug it seems to have a value. I have posted both view controllers.
It seems like the problem is in the `updateWeatherForLocation(location: finalName)`. I have checked to make sure all connections are made thru the storyboard.
I sure can't seem to figure it out!

```
            //Return the name of the city//

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
            let locationName = placemarks?.first?.locality ?? "Unknown Location"
            self.location.text = locationName

        }
}



@IBAction func foreCast(_ sender: Any) {

    nameText = location.text!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Week", sender: self)


        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! WeatherTableViewController
        vc.finalName = self.nameText


        }


}
    }


class WeatherTableViewController: UITableViewController,           UISearchBarDelegate {
var finalName = ""
@IBAction func close() {
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!


var forecastData = [Weather]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //location = finalName
    searchBar.delegate = self

    searchBar.text = finalName

    updateWeatherForLocation(location: finalName)



}



}
```

Comment: I don’t see the code that sets the search bar.

Comment: Sorry about that, its much cleaner now.

Comment: Thanks. Is your `searchBar` outlet connected in the storyboard? And you should probably be using a `UISearchController` instead of manually setting a `UISearchBar` in the storyboard, anyway.

Comment: I double checked the connection is storyboard, its connected. Would manually setting UISearchBar cause this or is it just better code to use UISearchController?